# how to bind drop down in edit template of kendo scheduler?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I am working on kendo scheduler and I need to add some extra text box and dropdowns to the create and edit of scheduler. I know extra dropdown can be added by adding the resource to scheduler, but in case of adding extra text box we have to add edit template. but in custom template I am not able to add the dropdown list for user appointment type with color specification. I have added a simple drop-down but with no color specification. I have this so far:
here is my .cshtml view code

```
@model List<FW.Model.UserColor>
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using Fairwater.UI.Filters
@using FW.Common.Helper
@using Fairwater.UI.Helper
<h5>Scheduler</h5>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<FW.Model.Appointments>()
    .Name("scheduler1")
    .Date(new DateTime(2015, 11, 11))

   .Editable(e => e.TemplateId("editor").Create(true).Confirmation(true))
    .Height(600)
    .Width(1000)
    .EndTime(new DateTime(2025,11,11,7,00,00))
    .Views(views =>
    {

       // views.DayView();
       // views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
        views.MonthView(monthviw=>monthviw.Selected(true));
    })
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
                    //.Resources(resource =>
                    //        {
                    //            resource.Add(m => m.BackgroundId)

                    //                 .Title("Background")
                    //                .DataTextField("BackgroundName")
                    //                .DataValueField("BackgroundId")
                    //                .Name("Background")
                    //                .DataColorField("Color")
                    //            .DataSource(x => x.Read(rs => rs.Action("GetBackgroundTypes", "Schedule", new { area = "Crew" })));

                    //        })
    .DataSource(d => d
            .Model(m =>
            {
                m.Id(f => f.AppointmentId);
                m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
               // m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);
                m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
            })
                .Read("CrewSchedulerRead", "Schedule")
                .Create("CreateAppointment", "Schedule")
                .Destroy("Appointment_Destroy", "Schedule")
                .Update("Appointment_Update", "Schedule")
                         .Events(x => x.Error("expError"))
    )
        )
    </div>
</div>
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="title">Subject</label>
        </div>
        <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="title">
            <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="title" data-bind="value: title">
        </div>
        <div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="title">Location</label>
        </div>
        <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="Location">
            <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="Location" data-bind="value: Location" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="BackgroundId">Background</label>
        </div>
    <div data-container-for="BackgroundId" class="k-edit-field">      
        <select id="BackgroundId" data-bind="value:BackgroundId" data-template="" data-role="dropdownlist" data-value-field="value" data-text-field="text">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <option style="background-color:red" value="@item.BackgroundId">@item.BackgroundName</option>
            }
        </select>      
    </div>  
    <div class="k-edit-label">
        <label for="recurrenceRule">Repeat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="recurrenceRule">
        <div data-bind="value: recurrenceRule" name="recurrenceRule" data-role="recurrenceeditor"></div>
    </div>
    </script>
```

I don't now am I on the right path or not, but I think I am close of it.
Thats what I have till now[image: thats what i have till now]
 [image: Ant That is what I want, the color dropdown, so user appointment display with their specific color in scheduler] That's what I want more, the color dorpdown. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. If anything not clear about my question please let me know in comments, I will happy to explain. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can add how many dropdowns or any other controls using resourses as

```
    .Resources(resource =>
{
    resource.Add(m => m.OwnerID)
        .Title("Trainers")
        .DataTextField("EMPNAME")
        .DataValueField("EMPID")
        .DataColorField("COLORCODE")
        .BindTo(@ViewBag.trainers);

    resource.Add(m => m.TypeID)
        .Title("Type")
        .Name("maintype")
        .DataTextField("TYPENAME")
        .DataValueField("TYPECODE")
        .BindTo(@ViewBag.lsttypes);

    })
```